# When I use @nuxtjs/auth to login, it sends a request with a different URL than the one I specified

Tags: vue.js, authentication, jwt, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

## What we want to solve

I am using the `@nuxtjs/auth'` module of Nuxt.js for login authentication, but when I use the `loginWith` method, I get an error because it jumps to an unspecified URL instead of the URL set in config. I need to know how and why this is happening.

URL set in config

```js
'/api/v1/auth/sign_in'
```

The actual URL being sent

```js
/api/auth/login
```

## Code

**config**

```js
  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http:localhost:3000'
  },

  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/user/login',
      logout: '/user/login',
      callback: false,
      home: '/'
    },
    strategines: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/api/v1/auth/sign_in', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
          logout: { url: '/api/v1/auth/sign_out', method: 'delete' },
          user: { url: '/api/v1/auth/user', method: 'get' }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

components

```js
import logoImg from '~/assets/images/login_logo.png'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      logoImg,
      userInfo: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async login () {
      await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          email: this.userInfo.email,
          password: this.userInfo.password
        }
      })
        .then(
          (response) => {
            localStorage.setItem('access-token', response.headers['access-token'])
            localStorage.setItem('client', response.headers.client)
            localStorage.setItem('uid', response.headers.uid)
            localStorage.setItem('token-type', response.headers['token-type'])
            return response
          },
          (error) => {
            return error
          }
        )
    }
  }
}
```

## Error

```
OST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Isn't it just the backend doing a redirect? What do you have if you try with Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typos in your config.

`strategines` -> `strategies`

`http:localhost:3000` -> `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize the mistake.